# How I use only Asio of Boost Library?

Tags: c++, boost, include, boost-asio

how I use **only the Asio of Boost Library** *without* adding any other library? Is that possible?

In the **Boost**, don't have the folder called "**lib**" with the **.a* files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Asio](http://think-async.com/) exists as as standalone library, entirely independent of Boost (this is the "original").

No need to search together the bits from Boost subdirectories if you don't want to use Boost, just download Asio and use that.  :-)

Comment: I've just downloaded the standalone Asio (1.48.0), and it appears to have a need for Boost (within `include\asio\detail\config.hpp`). Have I missed something? A #define perhaps?

Comment: @icabod define `ASIO_STANDALONE` and make sure you compile as at least C++11

Answer (score 5):

Since `Asio` is a header-only library, there are no `lib` files associated with it. You can extract only the absolutly needed header files with [`bcp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html), which is included.

Comment: Boost.Asio (as opposed to Asio) relies on Boost.System, which is not header-only; consequently, in order to use it, some linking is required.

Comment: @ildjarn: I think there was a possibility to use `Boost.Asio` without `Boost.System`?

Comment: Indeed -- by using Asio instead of Boost.Asio. :-] But if one wants to use _Boost_.Asio, they must link in Boost.System (and possibly Boost.Regex), as noted in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html).